# How can i use Access Token in laravel project

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt

I get now the Access Token from Lumen-API-JWT (Backend) but the question is how can i work with that in the laravel-8-Client (frontend) project

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In generally when we working with HTTP API or call need to authentication the user, Server will return the Access Token (JWT or whatever). Every API Request you need to bind that access token along with the header. Ex. **Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}**.

When you fail to bind the access token server will return unauthenticated HTTP status code with the relevant message.

Please refer below links,

https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/everything-you-want-to-know-about-authorization-headers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get now the Token from API-Lumen-Authentication (Access Token). The question is how can I implement that in the laravel-client (how I will save the token in Laravel and how the Login, Register look like) because i have now laravel 8 and I think token will not work with Fortify https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify

Comment: Laravel Fortify only provides the backend logic for session-based authentication and therefore is not intended for token-based API authentication.

If you need token-based API authentication, you can use either JWT libray or Passport depending on your needs. But You'll have to write a bit of code, in either case.

Comment: Thank you I will start to use JWT